# Artifact when rotateing elements with css

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/CraasHworks/pen/gPNjwW

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EYGk.png)

```
.wave{
  position: absolute;
  width: 28%;
  height: 28%;
  border-top: 16px solid rgb(204,200,200);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(204,200,200);
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
}
.rightWave{
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.leftWave{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#exampleTwo > div:nth-child(1){
  left: 15%;
  top: 30%;
}
#exampleTwo > div:nth-child(2){
  left: 54.8%;
  top: 30%;
}

<figure id="exampleTwo" class="icon">
   <div class="wave leftWave"></div><div class="wave rightWave"></div> </figure>
```

Okay this is a bit weird. Ive made this css "wave" icon before, copied the code and now it got an artifact and I can only get rid of it by rotating it back to 0deg og making it 100% border radius.

I'd like to understand what is going on here, If someone could point me to some documentation for this I would be gratefull!

Comment: Oh, It worked before because it used the color property of "red"; and not rgb, hex dosnt work either.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you see? in the link you sent it looks normal to me. Also in which browsers have you tested this?

Comment: done. You are right, the artifacts are only visible in firefox not Chrome...